# Android app crashing when switching from splash screen

Tags: java, android, xml

The app was working last week I was trying a few action bar tutorials today and it hasn't worked since I removed the code for those and I am pretty sure I removed all the changes to the code I made.  I was running the app on my phone so I do not have the error readout studio would give me it refuses to launch the emulator.  It just says Unfortunately, Doggie did has stopped when switching from the splash screen to login or home screens.

Splashscreen Java file

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    Thread splashThread = new Thread(){
    public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent startHomeScreen = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(startHomeScreen);
            }
        }
    };
    splashThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

---

```
Splashscreen xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/fulllogo"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="#2c7134" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}

public void sendProfile(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DogProfileActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

### }

Home xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid.HomeActivity"
android:background="@drawable/screenbackground">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ddlogo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ddlogo"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/selectprofiletext"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ddlogo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textColor="#2c7134"
    android:text="Select a profile or make a post:"
     />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:id="@+id/dog1image"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/selectprofiletext"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/dogpic"
    android:onClick="sendProfile"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:id="@+id/dog1num1"
    android:background="@drawable/num1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dog1num2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dog1num2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dog1num2" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:id="@+id/dog1num2"
    android:background="@drawable/num2"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ddlogo"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ddlogo" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add new dog"
    android:id="@+id/newdogbutton"
    android:background="#2c7134"
    android:allowUndo="true"
    android:textColor="#f3ca83"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="AddNewDog"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Login java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

final Button submitbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
/** Called when the user clicks the Login button */
public void sendHome(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

final Button registerbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RegisterButton);
/** Called when the user clicks the register button */
public void sendRegister(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegistrationActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

### }

Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="Registration" />
    <activity
        android:name=".NewDogActivity"
        android:label="Dog Information" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Login" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DogProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dog_profile"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

---

Styles xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for coloring the Toolbar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2c7134</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for coloring the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#245c2a</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#f3ca83</item>
</style>



</resources>
```

Logcat error readout
02-23 15:28:03.974 2186-2186/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
02-23 15:28:04.024 2186-2186/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid-2/lib/x86
02-23 15:28:04.255 2186-2196/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 132.833ms for cause Background
02-23 15:28:04.332 2186-2196/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9833(405KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 11MB/11MB, paused 63.266ms total 74.475ms
02-23 15:28:04.367 2186-2196/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 43(1776B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 11MB/15MB, paused 11.973ms total 21.908ms
02-23 15:28:04.374 2186-2217/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-23 15:28:04.472 2186-2217/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-23 15:28:04.556 2186-2217/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-23 15:28:04.556 2186-2217/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad6e0940, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-23 15:28:06.422 2186-2186/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-23 15:28:06.422 2186-2186/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid, PID: 2186
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:422)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:279)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:253)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                                  at cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:13)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
02-23 15:28:10.045 2186-2186/cs495capstone.edu.bsu.doggydid I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2186 SIG: 9

Comment: Post your logcat stack trace

Comment: Can you show the app scope? Some bars may have issues when the minimum SDK is lower than API 15

Comment: You're going to want to put `submitbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);` inside `onCreate()` and after `setContentView()` in `LoginActivity.java`. Same with any other `View` intializations you might have.

Comment: @fractalwrench I cant post a logcat stack trace you have to be able to run the app in studio I believe??  That is my whole problem I cant get the emulator to run I let it set for 30 minutes.

Comment: @pamobo0609 I have the minimum set at 14 I will raise it to 15, and target is at 23

Comment: @DanB alrighty! And well, if the error keeps showing, can you please post the Logcat output? Also, I have another way to make an splash, without using a `Thread.sleep(5000)` call that you could use, if necessary

Comment: @pamobo0609 going to try having a friend run it see if he can get a stack trace for everyone.

Comment: @DanB appreciated :)

Comment: @pamobo0609 added the logcat error readout at the bottom of the post.  Sorry it took so long just got it back from my friend

Comment: @fractalwrench just got logcat back from a friend that ran it for me sorry it took so long

Comment: @DanB `AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false}`. You' calling `windowActionBar` in your Theme specs

Comment: Try to comment it to see if the issue comes from there.

Comment: @pamobo0609 thank you it was that simple

Comment: @DanB did u fix it? Glad to read that and to help :)